# A code that gives the mode of the data (shouldn't use functions available under the statistics)

Tags: python, database, for-loop, if-statement, statistics

I am trying to write a code that gives the mode of the data. And I shouldn't use functions available under the statistics
module but I can use built-in functions such as max,min,sum,etc.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,3,4,2,1,3,2,1,3,5]
time=0
freq1=0
freq2=0
freq3=0
freq4=0
freq5=0
for i in list1:
    if list1[i]==1:
        time+=time
        freq1=time
    elif list1[i]==2:
        time+=time
        freq2=time
    elif list1[i]==3:
        time+=time
        freq3=time
    elif list1[i]==4:
        time+=time
        freq4=time
    elif list1[i]==5:
        time+=time
        freq5=time
list2=[freq1,freq2,freq3,freq4,freq5]
print(max(list2))
```

Here is what I get

```
0
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't match the posted results. Please edit your question with a proper [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong for a number of reasons. **First** of all, you should not need `time` for the program you wrote. **Second**, you are adding `time` to itself everytime. now `time` is 0, so even after multiple additions, you are getting 0. **Third**, you are iterating over all the elements, not their indices, so instead of checking for `list[i]` you need to check for `i`. So it should have been something like this:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,3,4,2,1,3,2,1,3,5]

freq1=0
freq2=0
freq3=0
freq4=0
freq5=0
for i in list1:
    if i==1:
        freq1 += 1
    elif i==2:
        freq2 += 1
    elif i==3:
        freq3 += 1
    elif i==4:
        freq4 += 1
    elif i==5:
        freq5 += 1
list2=[freq1,freq2,freq3,freq4,freq5]
print(max(list2))
```

But even after all this you will get the maximum occurrence of a value, not the value which occurs the maximum time. The result of the above program is `6`. That is the count of the mode `3` that occurs `6` times. Now, in order to get the mode itself, you need some other data structure, either list of lists, or list of tuples, but the best is dictionary.

So something like this would be the sweetest:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,3,4,2,1,3,2,1,3,5]
d = {}
for num in list1:
    d[num] = d.get(num,0) + 1
# at this point, d looks like this:
# {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 3, 5: 2}

# Then either:
print('mode =',max(d,key = lambda key:d[key]))
# outputs: 
# mode = 3

# or
print('mode = {0}, occurs {1} times'.format(*max(list(d.items()),key = lambda item:item[1])))
# outputs:
# mode = 3, occurs 6 times
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding time to time. time = 0. Time + time = 0 So the freq values are wrong. 
Fixing this by using:

```
time+=1
```

Will not work either unless you initiate a new time for each of your possible variables. You could just use freqn+=1 for each of your cases and it would work the same.

There are much more efficient ways to do this but thats the error in your code.